# Post-install Yum Remove Dependency

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

I've recently upgraded my PostgreSQL Server from 9.2 to 9.4. With these changes, I've updated a PostgreSQL Utilities RPMs POM.xml from

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<require>postgresql92-postgresql</require>
```

to

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<require>rh-postgresql94-postgresql</require>
```

and the new RPMs are installed as a pre-requisite to installing the utilities package.

What's the best way to yum-remove the old RPMs? (postgresql92-postgresql)

Should I just add it to the post-install script or can I do this via POM.xml as I have done to install the RPMs?

Comment: Sorry, either you're missing some details or your question doesn't make much sense as it is. How did you upgrade your postgres server (as if you have updated via rpm packages then the old ones have already been updated/replaced) You should probably add some basic context information if you want an answer ...

Comment: The Postgres Server upgrade was done using a binary which gets installed once the RPM is installed on the server. To get the RPM installed, I add it as a required dependency of the utilities RPM. The RPMs that were updated were not a simple yum upgrade <RPM>, instead these are completely new RPMs, so whilst the new require will install the new PG server, the old RPMs still stay installed on the system

Comment: Sorry, that sounds even more confusing to me. Care to mention why in particular you don't simply use the upstream postgres packages? If you can't, then you should probably read up on basics of rpm packaging. If you create a new package with a different name, but basically the same contents then those are completely different packages to rpm and will usually conflict. Normally you would only bump up the version number and/or the release. If the version is in the package name like in the example from your .xml file, then that is usually the problem.